# symfony console make:migration and --env option not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working on my first symfony (6.3) project with TDD in mind.
I've created some doctrine ORM entities and added fields time to time.
For the first integration test I've ran **"symfony console make:migration"** without **--env="test"** but like it was the first time I run it, it was ok, the sqlite database and all the tables were created.

When I run it the second time with **--env="test"** the command returned :

```
There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace.                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                           
You may be looking for a command provided by the "MakerBundle" which is currently not installed. Try running "composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev".
```

I've created the project with "symfony new --webapp --version=6.3 my_project" and therefore the makerbundle is in the require-dev section.

I'm a newbie so I'm missing something obvious here.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate why you want to create a database schema for your test environment? Your **database schema** should **not** differ per environment (`dev`/`prod`/`test`), your **database connection** however could. Since the `MakerBundle` is in the `require-dev` section, it should only run/be available in the `dev` environment. Eventhough the error message is somewhat vague (the `MakerBundle` does not exists in the `test` env.), [this is the main reason](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/100#issuecomment-353881536). You can also confirm this in `/config/bundles.php`, where the following code lives:

```
Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
```

The `'dev' => true` part confirms that the `MakerBundle` only is available in the `dev` environment.

TLDR;
You should only make migrations in the `dev` environment by running `symfony console make:migration` (there is no need to add --env=test).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sape! No i don't want a separate schema structure for the test env but a separate connection (an another sqlite file). But it seems  simpler to run it against the dev database.

Comment: Happy to help. In that case, create another env file: `.env.test`, in which you specificy another database connection. The schema is the same, however, you use another connection (and database) for running your test. You can also find this in the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#customizing-environment-variables).